# When can I start accessing localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, domcontentloaded

I am building small browser app as my first fun project with newer web technologies (new, when you consider that last time I've really played with JS/PHP/CSS/HTML was around 10 years ago). I want to create a theme switcher. It's quite easy to do, but I want user selection to be stored in localStorage and here's my question. Obviously I want to be able to set page style as soon as possible (through setting class on body element), so DOMContentLoaded event should be the right time to do this, but can I use localStorage at this point? It might be hard to just test it, as with not much content to load, it might always work until something unexpected happens and it won't. I just want to be sure, whether I have to wait for full document to load.

P.S.

I know it would be easier with server side setting managed through cookie, but for some reason, I am working with dynamically generated static pages (server generates static pages once it has anything new to work on, and user only loads static html files without any live content generation), so I can't go this way.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is "too soon" to use localStorage. It's not part of the page, so it's not initialised on page load or anything.

Comment: `localStorage` is a browser API. So irrespective of your pages state, it will be available. So even if you write an IIFE in HEAD tag of your page, it will still be available